# How to use page-cursor concept in cobol?

Tags: sql, cursor, cobol, cics

I have a database of large details to be displayed in a single CICS map. I thought of using page-cursor concept in fethcing every few rows and display it in CICS map. But I dont know the syntax for page-cursor in COBOL. Can somebody help me with providing snippets?

Comment: Since there are several ways and elements to generally allow scrolling of the data, one of which will be standard at your site, this question is not a good fit here. Locate a similar program, ask your colleagues/technical support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a curson and use the "optimize for X rows" hint on your declare curson statemen with DB2.  That would be somewhere around 20 rows usually for a 3270 screen.